# Digits to month year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

Is there is easy way to turn digits that represent the month and year into text?

So for example:

```
1208
109
209
309
409
```

Would be:

```
December 2008
January 2009
February 2009
March 2009
April 2009
```

The only way I can think of doing it currently is via a series of if/else statements.

Comment: You should show what you attempted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, the idea is to:

- convert the numbers to strings
- use [`.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to load strings into datetime objects
- use [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to dump datetimes back to strings in a desired format (`%B %Y` in your case)

Demo:

```
In [1]: l = [1208, 109, 209, 309, 409]

In [2]: [datetime.strptime(str(item), "%m%y").strftime("%B %Y") for item in l]
Out[2]: ['December 2008', 'January 2009', 'February 2009', 'March 2009', 'April 2009']
```